# Blue Screen of Death - Laptop Crash Every Evening - BCCode: 1000007e

Tags: crash, bsod

Thanks a lot for taking your time and reading the post, but my laptop has been having BSOD issue every single night for the past little while, out of no reason and I have not install any additional software on it (not that I can recall), here is the error message when the computer was rebooted:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:    BlueScreen
  OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:    1000007e
  BCP1:    FFFFFFFFC0000005
  BCP2:    FFFFF88001AB0F24
  BCP3:    FFFFF880030A2968
  BCP4:    FFFFF880030A21C0
  OS Version:    6_1_7601
  Service Pack:    1_0
  Product:    256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\121612-92680-01.dmp
  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-95082-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

I have managed to find the .dmp file and has attached it here: http://llst.net/BSOD/121612-92680-01.dmp

Unfortunately I can not find the sysdata.xml file anymore. I suspect it was deleted after I clicked on Check For Solutions button.

Here is the hardware info for my laptop: http://llst.net/BSOD/HardwareInfo.html

And the software info: http://llst.net/BSOD/SoftwareInfo.html

Thanks a lot for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your HDD for errors (SMART values and run chkdsk /F), because the VSS driver causes the bugcheck:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Some common problems are exception code 0x80000003.  This means a hard
coded breakpoint or assertion was hit, but this system was booted
/NODEBUG.  This is not supposed to happen as developers should never have
hardcoded breakpoints in retail code, but ...
If this happens, make sure a debugger gets connected, and the
system is booted /DEBUG.  This will let us see why this breakpoint is
happening.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff88001ab0f24, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: fffff880030a2968, Exception Record Address
Arg4: fffff880030a21c0, Context Record Address

Debugging Details:
------------------



EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

FAULTING_IP: 
volsnap!VspAllocateDiffAreaSpace+c4
fffff880`01ab0f24 488b4748        mov     rax,qword ptr [rdi+48h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff880030a2968 -- (.exr 0xfffff880030a2968)
ExceptionAddress: fffff88001ab0f24 (volsnap!VspAllocateDiffAreaSpace+0x00000000000000c4)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000048
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000048

CONTEXT:  fffff880030a21c0 -- (.cxr 0xfffff880030a21c0)
rax=fffff880030a2c08 rbx=fffffa8006413a30 rcx=fffffa8006413a30
rdx=fffffa8006e06f78 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff88001ab0f24 rsp=fffff880030a2ba0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=fffffa8006e06ff0  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000000 r12=fffffa800d373010 r13=fffffa800619e190
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
volsnap!VspAllocateDiffAreaSpace+0xc4:
fffff880`01ab0f24 488b4748        mov     rax,qword ptr [rdi+48h] ds:002b:00000000`00000048=????????????????
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000048

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800034b5100
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800034b51c0
 0000000000000048 Nonpaged pool

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
volsnap!VspAllocateDiffAreaSpace+c4
fffff880`01ab0f24 488b4748        mov     rax,qword ptr [rdi+48h]

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7E

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff88001ab22a3 to fffff88001ab0f24

STACK_TEXT:  
volsnap!VspAllocateDiffAreaSpace
volsnap!VspWriteVolumePhase25
volsnap!VspWriteVolumePhase22
volsnap!VspWorkerThread
nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
nt!KiStartSystemThread



SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  volsnap!VspAllocateDiffAreaSpace+c4

IMAGE_NAME:  volsnap.sys


    Loaded symbol image file: volsnap.sys
    Mapped memory image file: c:\sym\dl\volsnap.sys\4CE792C84c000\volsnap.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\volsnap.sys
    Image name: volsnap.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 10:20:08 2010 (4CE792C8)
    CheckSum:         000527ED
    ImageSize:        0004C000
    File version:     6.1.7601.17514
    Product version:  6.1.7601.17514
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        3.7 Driver
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     volsnap.sys
    OriginalFilename: volsnap.sys
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.17514
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
    FileDescription:  Volume Shadow Copy Driver
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Thanks but my hard drive is an SSD, would the chkdisk command still works? And how can I check the SMART values? Thanks for your help!

Comment: chdsk also works for a SSD. SMART values can be detected with tools like CrystalDiskInfo (http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html). Also update the firmware of your SSD.

Comment: Thanks for your help @magicandre1981, I have tried to run chkdsk /F but for some reason the check for D drive was cancelled automatically while the check for C and E drive went on with no error, here is the crystalmark report, may I know what value I should be looking at? Thanks! EDIT: Can't paste it here so here you go: http://pastebin.com/kwLUZ8EY

Comment: According to report the drive is ok and you already use the latest firmware. How often did you have this crash?

Comment: Every evening, I left my laptop on for the whole night and the next morning when I wake up, all I see is a blank screen although the power and hard drive lights are on, which indicate the laptop is still running, and it is not sleeping as well since I have disabled sleeping while it is on AC power.

Comment: disable the automatic creation of system restore points and the automatic maintenance and create complete backups with an imaging software instead.